# Jquery .post() remote submitting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So Im trying to use jquery's .post function to submit a form and return the results on the same page. I've tried using the example found in [jquery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The form is getting submitted successfully but nothing gets returned to the form page.

I have my JS set up like:

```
    <form id="test_form" method="post" action="test3.php">
        <input type="radio" name="zip" id="zip" value="10001" />
        <input type="radio" name="keyword" id="keyword" value="GPS" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="result" ></div>

    <script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#test_form").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        zip = $form.find( 'input[name="zip"]' ).val(),
        keyword = $form.find( 'input[name="keyword"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.post( url, { keyword: keyword,  zip: zip },
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#form_results' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

the relevant portion of the form script on test3.php looks like:

```
<div id="form_results">
<script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[

   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://mydomain.com/openx/www/delivery/rtl.php':'http://mydomain.com/openx/www/delivery/rtl.php');

   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);

   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';

   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);

   document.write ("?zoneid=4");

   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);



//you Should pass your Keyword

   document.write ('&amp;keyword=<?php echo urlencode($_POST["keyword"]);?>');

//you Should pass your Zipcode

 document.write ('&amp;zipcode=<?php echo urlencode($_POST["zip"]);?>');



   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);

   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));

   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));

   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));

   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));

   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");

   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");

//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='http://mydomain.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a9d134b1&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://mydomain.com/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=4&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a9d134b1' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
  </div>
```

What I am doing wrong here? Why doesn't it return the results into the #result div? I've watched the headers, so I know that the data is getting passed successfully.

Comment: In Chrome, do the post and look in the Network section. See what the response is.

Comment: Also check out the data being returned from the callback in the $.post() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I have discovered that there is no possible solution to this problem, short of implementing a hack like JSON-P. It doesn't work because it violates the same-domain policy. Thanks to anyone who looked at this and attempted to figure out what was going on.